# Colorbar in matplotlib GIF: why labels disappear?

Tags: matplotlib, animation, gif, colorbar

I am making GIFs in matplotlib with FuncAnimation , and I need to add a colorbar with ticks under my Gif but I only obtain this. Why my colorbar has no ticks in the gif while in the jupyter notebook where i am working i have the image with colorbar and ticks?

this is how I made the the code for the colorbar:

```
img = plt.imshow(temp,cmap = cmap,extent=extent,vmin = -20,vmax = 45,transform=img_proj,origin = 'upper')
cbar = plt.colorbar(img, ax=ax, orientation='horizontal', fraction=0.04, pad=0.04)
title1 = cbar.ax.set_title('°C',fontsize = 16, fontweight = 'bold',pad = 5)
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=8)
```

[image]

Comment: An animated GIF is a very old format, and can only represent 255 different colors (also the files tend to grow extremely large). To show small text, a lot of gray values are needed. You might consider a format such as mpeg to have a full range of colors. Alternatively, you could consider saving the colorbar is a separate PNG file and showing the animanted gif and the colorbar as separate image files to your viewers.

Comment: thanks for your reply, but the GIF is  made for a tweet so, there is no so much flexibility on things to handle..

Comment: Your colorbar is spilling off the bottom of the figure.  Initialize the figure with figure(constrained_layout=True).  You can probably also remove most of the manual padding if you do that.